# Authenticating to BigQuery REST API via OAuth2 from Node.js

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery

Newbie trying to figure out how to get a Node.js application to authenticate and query Google BigQuery, trying to adapt [this CodeLab tutorial from Java](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/gettingstartedwithjava#createandauth).  What step might i be missing?

First I create this Oauth2 URL using my clientid:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
    client_id=1047877053699-den6kbs4v3f2bft6clonsirkj1pc7t6j.apps.googleusercontent.com
    &scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery
    &redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback
    &access_type=offline
    &response_type=code
```

This successfully reaches Google, which prompts

> **A third party service is requesting permission to access your Google Account.**

Agreeing that generates a second prompt:

> Nodejs_Test is requesting permission to: 
>   View and manage your data in Google BigQuery

Agreeing to that, the callback URL is called, with a parameter `accessToken`.

I *think* the following url should list tables in my BigQuery project/dataset:

https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/1047877053699/datasets/visits&accessToken=4%2FC196NizZwlNgWSt5oNqQwendmLNW.0vgUrlGJ6kMRshQV0ieZDApig3NfcgI

But calling with or  without the accessToken returns the following message that "Login Required".

```
 {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

I know you can't repeat the code because of permissions, expired tokens, etc.  But I wonder what step I might be missing conceptually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried sending the accesstoken as an authorization header rather than as a url parameter?

as in

```
https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/1047877053699/datasets/visits
Authorization: OAuth Your-access-token-here-not-urlencoded
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it to work.  The learning curve was multistep, but this provided the right keywords to latch on .

Answer (score 1):

FYI - looks like you originally used the parameter `accessToken` in the URL.  It should instead by `access_token`, which looks like it works fine.  Of course, Jordan's suggestion of using a Header is better if you're able to do it though-- it's more secure as it's unlikely to get logged in access logs, proxy server logs, etc.