# 401 error when making post call to big query

Tags: post, google-bigquery

I have been trying to make an rest api call to big query using the below command:

```
curl -X POST -d "query=SELECT * FROM [projname:datasetname.Tablename] LIMIT 20" "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projname/queries?key=AIzaSyAHRqP3cARj2Pd45by01S9vlv7frjEbjXc?access_token=i_g6FuzeY2hPMgh0p5Zf_Flw"
```

But I get the 401 error "Login required". Thats the reason in addition to the key, I have provided the access token as well. But did not get any response.

Please let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: Firstly, why are you trying to use `cURL`? Is this a requirement? There are plenty of good client libs for calling the BigQuery API. Or the API explorer, and even the `gcloud/bq` CLI tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using a '?' before access_token when you probably want '&': https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projname/queries?key=AIzaSyAHRqP3cARj2Pd45by01S9vlv7frjEbjXc&access_token=i_g6FuzeY2hPMgh0p5Zf_Flw

In addition to that, you might consider sending authorization as a header rather than a param: [Authenticating to BigQuery REST API via OAuth2 from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989001/authenticating-to-bigquery-rest-api-via-oauth2-from-node-js)